# store database passwords?

Tags: php, database, .htaccess, passwords

there is many method used to store database password , here is some :

1. store passwords in a congif.php file and then include the file when needed
2. store passwords as php environment variables
3. store password in the apache congif file

and to be sure the passwords are safe

1. save the config.php file out of root , or protect it with .htaccess
2. hide php environment variables

can you explain a little:

1. how to put some files out of root , and is it safe against all directory traversal attacks ?
2. is the .htaccess enough to secure a php file containing passwords ?
3. how to hide php environment variables ? is it done by disabling phpinfos() function ?
4. is storing passwords in apache configuration file only available on vps hosting ?

and thank you for help

Comment: This set of questions is much too broad and will lead to opinionated answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: looking only for one opinion , to decide which method use

Comment: One opinion? If you only need one opinion then send an e-mail to a developer that you know and work with that opinion.

Comment: Jay is definitely right, but in the case of PHP and databases, you generally store the passwords as some hash sum (md5 being the most popular iirc) in the user table of your website. File system passwords tend to get bogged down with a lot of users, as the file size of the config.php would get too large. And why would you want to hide PHP environment variables, if you're working in PHP?

Comment: not any opinion ^_^ , i am looking for one real professional opinion and i dont know one . so i posted this question here

Comment: jhecht i am not talking about users passwords !! i am talking about passwords used to open a connection to a database

Comment: How are you going to decide if one of us is "professional" enough? o_O

Comment: well ^_^ i am not going to decide , if anyone can help then thanks

Comment: I'm not a "Real Professional", but I pretend to be one on the internet.

Comment: @Sammitch  you know what is wrong in this world ? take this example : you can cook an egg in your home , but you are not a cooker in some restaurant , so you will not say i am a freelancer cooker ^_^ , because people will eat and will discover you lied ... but when it comes to internet and development , everybody say i am a freelancer even if the only thing he know is to change html headers or images , and most people wont discover he lie until they meet a real developer ... you see what i mean

Comment: @Sammitch as an advice i can tell you this , find what you really love do to , and what you're really good at , learn , practice , and then go on you are a professional in what you are created for - by god- , the only thing you have to do is to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely include your configuration variables in a separate file with the correct Unix permissions e.g. 644.

A `config.php` file could look like:

```
<?php
define (DB_USER, "mysql_user");
define (DB_PASSWORD, "mysql_password");
define (DB_DATABASE, "database_name");
define (DB_HOST, "localhost");
?>
```

And your main class could look like:

```
require ("config.php");
public class DatabaseConnect
{
    function __construct()
    {
        mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die('Could not connect to MySQL server.');
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    }

}
```

**Edit**

To prevent access to files with the .htaccess file, use:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And add what ever extensions your need.

**Edit 2**

Add this to the page that you want to only be included (not called directly).

```
<?php
if(!defined('MyConst')) {
   die('Direct access not permitted');
}
?>
```

then on the pages that include it add

```
<?php
define('MyConst', TRUE);
?>
```

Comment: is the right files permission enough to be secure ? and what about storing this file out of root ? or inside root but with .htaccess protection ?

Comment: I will edit my post with a way to stop files from being accessed with .htaccess

Comment: what about storing the config.php file out of root ? and how protect it against directory traversal attacks , if you know ?

Comment: The config file shouldn't be vulnerable to directory traversal since at the very least php will parse it and it will be displayed to the user as a blank page. You could store the config file out of the root but I don't really think that it's necessary.

Comment: disable remote file include is also needed , if i can include the config file from a remote server with python then i will see it as text

Comment: Just edited post with another edit

Comment: in addition to protection by constant you can add if ( url contain name of a page which should only be included ) then die ...

Comment: Yes that is also a good idea. You could add the URL string to your config file as a constant so that you can easily change it if you change urls.

Comment: thank you a lot , and sorry for the bad English i use , this is my best , i talk french not English ^_^

Comment: Not a problem! Good luck!